CORS response not working in some routes in Laravel 11
I'm creating an application using Angular 16 for the frontend and Laravel 11 for the backend, everything worked well in my local project but after hosting it, some routes like add to cart / upload file is returning a CORS error XHR in the console, for example when i hit add to cart i get an unexpected error occurred and when i opened the console i see that the error CORS appeared and there is no access-control-allow-origin is missing in the network , although the item was added to the cart , I don't understand why this problem is only in my hosted project and why is it only appearing for certain routes.
And for my cors.php file here is my code :
<?php
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
?>

Does anyone have an idea what seems to be the problem?
My domain names are like this:
for the front => www.localhost:4200 / www.frontdemo.*******.com
and the back => www.localhost:8000 / www.backdemo.*******.com
Local and hosted project respectfully.
Edit:
after a deep look here is what i'm getting for each POST request:
my console screenshot

in general, for https, and requests with credentials you can't wildcard.  Explicitly list the allowed origins, methods, etc..  (don't use "*")

Are you redirecting to the login route or similar on authentication error?

@browsermator i already tried that and didnt work,it only trigered other routes to cause cors error

@puklipo i dont have authentification error , i have the error when i use add to cart or upload file and yes you must be authentificated for those routes

If everything worked fine in your local environment  you can check 2 things. First, your frontend requests : make sure to put the "/"at the end of your request url /cart/ and not /cart , then for POST , PUT , DELETE requests check if their is no firewall blocking it as it's blocked by default (if your GET requests work check for this).
